# Can I set up Visual Studio to unload all projects, than choose 1 project and only load its dependencies recursively?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have a large C# solution, in which projects form a tree of clustered nodes - there is a core of ~50 projects, and 10+ clusters of ~5 projects depending only on the core, but still part of the same solution. Loading the whole thing is slow, so we tried adding smaller solutions alongside it, each only containing the core and one cluster. This is a bit cumbersome to set-up and maintain.

I'm thinking: each cluster has a 'head' project, which is the startup project of a particular web application, nothing depends on it, it depends on the rest of the cluster, that depends on core projects. So, is there any tool/script where I can set up Visual Studio to unload all projects, then choose 1 project and only load its dependencies recursively?

**Update for Visual Studio 2019**

There is now built-in functionality for this [Filtered solutions in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/filtered-solutions?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Workaround: Create a script which will automatically generate new SLN files for you. :-) If the structure of projects is as you described, it must be quite easy to generate these SLN files automatically. :-)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Michele Ferracin Visual Studio Professional 2017

Comment: I know it is not what is asked but, if you have that number of dependencies, would no be more manageable to create some nuget packages and then import them?

Comment: Nope, not in our case. We actively use nuget packages where we can, based on what changes together and what is deployed together. We have dozens of microservices accessed via clients distributed with nuget, but this is our orchestration core, having the routing logics in one solution eases its development and maintainability greatly. Equally as important - monolithic routing logics is much easier to research (at least until we get the cloud), and in big enterprise systems that do actual work tend to end up as source of truth for business process. Documentation rots, only code tells the truth.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a Visual Studio 2017 extension to handle loading and unloading projects based on references graph. It is available in [Visual Studio marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=IvanKoshelev.IKoshelev-ProjectFocuser). Source code is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/IKoshelev/IKoshelev.ProjectFocuser).

Additionally, settings that control which projects should be loaded and unloaded on solution opening are stored in the `suo` file kept inside `.vs` folder in solution root. This file is usually not kept under version control, as such, it is individual per each solution checkout (technically - per each copy of a solution). If you want to be able to switch between loading entire solution or just a part of it before you open it in Visual Studio - you can prepare a corresponding `suo` file by unloading projects you don't need (the extension above will help you), saving your solution and making a copy of `suo` file. When you will need this setup again - just restore that copy to its original location.